# IBM Worklight - windows 8 tablet run time javascript exception

Tags: jquery, windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

While running my app for Windows 8 tablet, I am getting runtime exception in jQuery lib.

> Unhandled exception at line 1469, column 3 in
>   ms-appx://6059b213-0a33-4d20-8429-fc91e6f329d9/www/default/js/jquery-1.9.1.js

steps taken in my project:

1. created a new worklight project
2. added the below scripts manually to default .html file (can't use script tags in Stackoverflow...):

> script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" 
>   script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"

3. commented out this line: `<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>`

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiPPy.png
   [image: before login]

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcJPC.png
   [image: after login]

Comment: Please edit the question with the steps you've taken in Eclipse and then in Visual Studio; for me there is no such error. Worklight 6.0 ships with jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: we are using worklight version 5.0.5, with jquery 1.9.1 lib, any idea about this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.9.1 will not work with win8. Two options here

1. (preferred) use jQuery 1.8.x. It is enough for jQuery mobile 1.3.x
2. Patch jQuery 1.9.1. Find this line

   body.appendChild( container ).appendChild( div );

and replace it with

```
    if (typeof(MSApp) !== "undefined"){
        MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function(){
            body.appendChild( container ).appendChild( div );
        });
    } else {
        body.appendChild( container ).appendChild( div );
    }
```

Comment: Hi Anton, I tried this but I have 2 issues, first :- I have lots of javascript errors in console, which doesn't allow me to create a .appx file for distribution, second :- After I login in the app, I get some run time js exception on throw clause in js lib file, please refer screen shots attached.

Comment: About the errors, see if this post helps: http://incloud.de/2012/08/windows-8-using-jquery-for-app-development

Comment: hi Idan, I have tried this link and patched version of the js file, but still I get some run time exceptions on sample alert app.

Comment: you tell me if it's ok:)

Comment: 1.8.0 works, but it given me the following later in the app when i try tapping on some buttons. Unhandled exception at line 1482, column 21 in ms-appx://6059b213-0a33-4d20-8429-fc91e6f329d9/www/default/wlclient/js/worklight.js
0x800c001c - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content.